# Sitecore azure Deployment

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have an Azure subscription with location India. When using Sitecore Azure module the location for farms not contain India in that. Can I use that for Sitecore Azure deployment using the Sitecore Azure module?

Comment: This sounds more like an issue to file with Sitecore Support.

Answer (score 0):

The data centers appear to be defined in the /App_Config/AzureVendors/Microsoft.xml file.  You can add a data center node to that XML something like this:

```
<vendor name="Microsoft">
  <datacenters>
    ...
    <datacenter name="West India">
      <coordinates left="66%" top="56.5%" />
    </datacenter>
  </datacenters>
  ...
</vendor>
```

Note, however, that according to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services, the India regions do not support all Cloud Service sizes.

I tested adding a new data center and it appears on the map and the menu seems to work.  However, **I have not actually tried deploying, so proceed with caution.**